# Compare columns in Dataframe with inconsistent type values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'RMDS': ['10.686000','NYSE_XNAS','0.472590','qrtr'], 'Mstar': ['10.690000', 'NYSE_XNAS', '0.473590','mnthly']})
```

Dataframe df will look like this:

```
    Mstar       RMDS
0   10.690000   10.686000
1   NYSE_XNAS   NYSE_XNAS
2   0.473590    0.472590
3   mnthly      qrtr
```

I want to compare value of 'RMDS' with 'Mstar' and type of dataframe is 'object',this is huge dataframe and I need to compare rounded values

mask = np.around(pd.to_numeric(df.Mstar), 2) != np.around(pd.to_numeric(df.RMDS), 2)

df_Difference = df[mask]

since values in columns are not consistent so whenever string values are coming like 'qrtr' , above logic is failing as I am using pd.to_numeric but still i wanted to compare 'qrtr' from 'RMDS' to 'mnthly' in 'Mstar'

Is there any way I could handle this type of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to convert what you can, then `.fillna` to get everything back that wasn't converted.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = np.round(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'),2).fillna(df)
#        RMDS      Mstar
#0      10.69      10.69
#1  NYSE_XNAS  NYSE_XNAS
#2       0.47       0.47
#3       qrtr     mnthly

df.RMDS == df.Mstar
#0     True
#1     True
#2     True
#3    False
#dtype: bool
```

---

Alternatively, define your own function and use `.applymap`

```
def my_round(x):
    try:
        return np.round(float(x),2)
    except ValueError:
        return x

df = df.applymap(my_round)
```